# update status function should not refresh which onchange the dropdownlist using mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

When onclick the status update then only corresponding row should be refresh . before that i written the drop down onchange function based on that only table row is display.

**cs.html:**

```
<section class="card ">
            <div class="card-block">
                <h5 class="with-border m-t-lg">View Module List</h5>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">
                        <fieldset class="form-group">
                            <label class="form-label" for="exampleInput">Domain Name</label>
                            @Html.DropDownList("DomainID", null, "--- Select Domain Name ---", new { @class = "select2-arrow" })
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="table-responsive" id="findValue" style="display:none;">
                    <table id="example" class="display table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%;">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>S#</th>
                                <th>Module Name</th>
                                <th>Url</th>
                                <th>Roles</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
```

**Dropdown based on view tables code:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#DomainID").change(function () {

            var id = $(this).val();
            $("#example tbody tr").remove();

            $.ajax({

                type: 'POST',

                url: '@Url.Action("ViewModules")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: id },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var items = '';
                        $.each(data.EmpList, function (i, item) {
                            $("#findValue").show();

                            /*Find Role here - Comparing Emp List ModuleId to RoleList ModuleId*/

                            var RoleName = $(data.role).filter(function (index, item) {
                                return item.ModuleID == item.ModuleID
                            });

                            if (item.ParentModuleID == -1) {

                                item.ModuleName = " -- " + item.ModuleName
                            }
                            else {
                                item.ModuleName = item.ModuleName
                            }

                            var Status = '';
                            if (item.Status == "Y") {
                                Status = '<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" data-status=' + item.Status + ' data-id=' + item.ModuleID + ' class="user-status" title="Disable status"><img src="/img/Active.png" height="22" width="42"/></a>'
                            } else {
                                Status = '<a href="JavaScript:void(0)" data-status=' + item.Status + ' data-id=' + item.ModuleID + ' class="user-status" title="Active status"><img src="/img/InActive.png" height="22" width="42"/></a>'
                            }

                            var rows = "<tr>"
                            + "<td>" + (i + 1) + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.ModuleName + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + item.Url + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + RoleName[i].RoleName + "</td>"
                            + "<td>" + '<a href="@Url.Action("EditModules", "Account")?id=' + item.ModuleID + '" class="font-icon font-icon-pencil" title="Edit"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + Status + "</td>"
                            + "</tr>";
                        $('#example tbody').append(rows);
                    });
                },
                error: function (ex) {
                    var r = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                    alert("Message: " + r.Message);
                    alert("StackTrace: " + r.StackTrace);
                    alert("ExceptionType: " + r.ExceptionType);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**Update status Code**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#example tbody").on('click', '.user-status', function () {
                var getId = $(this).data('id');
                var status = $(this).attr('data-status');

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateStatusModule")',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { ModuleID: getId },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            alert(data.message);
                            $("#example tbody").load("/Account/UpdateStatusModule");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (ex) {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve Sub Categories : ' + ex);
                    }
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
```

i written the drop down onchange function based on that only table row is display. When onclick the status update then only corresponding row should be refresh  onchange no value should not be change

```
#region Update Status
        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateStatusModule(int ModuleID)
        {
            try
            {
                int refID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["RefID"]);
                int typeID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["ComTypeID"]);

                if (ModelState.IsValid && refID > 0)
                {
                    userType type = new userType();
                    type.UpdateStatusModule(ModuleID);
                }
                return Json(new { success = true, message = "updated successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }

        }
        #endregion
```

Answer (score 0):

If you append html after the initialization it can't work. 
You need to register events on document(without $(document).ready)

```
$(document).on("change","#DomainID", function () {
    alert("domain changed");
 }).on('click', '.user-status', function () {
    alert("clicked");
 });
```

For async POST:

```
$.post("MyUrl",{myId: myId},function(data){
    do wathever
}).fail(function(x,y,z){
    alert("ops");
});
```

More simple